# If $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b} = \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{c}$ then $\textbf{b}= \textbf{c}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

If **a** $\cdot$ **b** = **a**$\cdot$**c**, when is **b** $=$ **c**?

We get  $\mid$**a**$\mid$$\mid$**b**$\mid \cos{\theta} = \mid$**a**$\mid$**c**$\mid \cos{\phi}$

and $\dfrac{\mid \textbf{a}\mid \mid \textbf{b}\mid }{\mid \textbf{a} \mid \textbf{c}\mid } =\dfrac{\cos{\phi}}{\cos{\theta}}$.

Then if $\theta = \phi$

We have **b** $=$ **c**.

Thx!

Comment: If $\theta=\phi$ you have $|\mathbf b|=|\mathbf c|$. But, unless you are on a plane, $\theta=\phi$ does not mean that $\mathbf b=\mathbf c$.

Comment: You need to be careful if $\bf{a} = \bar{0}$.

Comment: Thx guys, thx for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf b}={\bf a}\cdot {\bf c}$ is equivalent to writing ${\bf a}\cdot ({\bf b}-{\bf c})=0$. This is equivalent to saying that ${\bf a}$ is orthogonal to ${\bf b}-{\bf c}$. So for this to imply that ${\bf b}-{\bf c}=0$, we need to have ${\bf a}$ pointing in the same direction as ${\bf b}-{\bf c}$.

Comment: Or the exact opposite direction, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost answered the question yourself: the only way is if $\mathbf{a}$ points in the same direction as $\mathbf{b}$.

This should make sense, because a single number (i.e. 1 dimensional vector) $\mathbf{a}·\mathbf{c}$ connecting $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ should not be enough to reconstruct an $n$-dimensional vector.

There is a situation when dot products can reveal the original vector, using a basis of $ℝ^n$, $\{e_1,…,e_n\}$. For example, for $ℝ^3$, $\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$ is a basis. The result is

$$ \text{if for all }i, \  \mathbf{a}· e_i = \mathbf{b}· e_i \text{, then } \mathbf{a}= \mathbf{b}$$